# PostgreSQL update + join with an additional WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I need to use JOIN in my UPDATE so that I would only fill the value of the column where the condition applies.

I was trying to do this, but I receive an error saying "syntax error at or near 'LEFT'":

```
UPDATE products_mpn SET scrap = 5
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = products_mpn.product
WHERE products.category_id = 101 OR products.category_id = 104
```

I have found that I could join the tables this way:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.c1 = new_value
FROM t2
WHERE t1.c2 = t2.c2;
```

But the issue is that I can not use my specific WHERE clause then. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE products_mpn 
SET scrap = 5
WHERE product IN ( SELECT id 
FROM products
WHERE category_id IN (101,104))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE products_mpn SET scrap = 5 WHERE product = ( SELECT product FROM products_mpn
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = products_mpn.product
WHERE products.category_id = 101 OR products.category_id = 104)
```